# I want to handle the state of call in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I want to get the state of phone call either it in dialed, connected or disconnected...

I tried my self but i cant get the state.

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:@"9723539389"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];

CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call)
{
    if(CTCallStateDialing)
    {
        NSLog(@"Dialing");
    }
    if(CTCallStateConnected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connected");
    }
    if(CTCallStateDisconnected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Disconnected");
    }
};
```

but the problem is that the CTCallCenter block never called... I am currently worked in iOS 7

Comment: `telprompt` is not an official scheme and should therefore not be used. If Apple decides to remove it in some future version of iOS you app will stop working.

Comment: @rckoenes agreed but how many people actually do use this and Apple have just ignored them using it? I myself have multiple apps that use this. I suppose Apple are doing a little bit of a crackdown on things recently so maybe they might start coming down on this a bit more.

Comment: maybe your `callcenter` object is released automatically when the scope is done, because no one keeps it alive outside of the scope – if you are using `ARC` of course.

Answer (score 5):

You should check the CTCall's callState property in order to catch it

[Use a cellular call’s CTCall object to obtain an identifier for the call and to determine the call’s state.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html)

```
 extern NSString const *CTCallStateDialing;
 extern NSString const *CTCallStateIncoming;
 extern NSString const *CTCallStateConnected;
 extern NSString const *CTCallStateDisconnected;
```

are string constants. You for loop doesn't make sense.

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:@"9723539389"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];

self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

[callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall* call)
{
    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
    {
        NSLog(@"Connected");
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
    {
        NSLog(@"Dialing");
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
    {
        NSLog(@"Disconnected");

    } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
    {
        NSLog(@"Incoming");
    }

}];
```

**NOTE:**

```
  @property(nonatomic, strong) CTCallCenter *callCenter;
```

**should be declared in Appdelegate and retain it. Otherwise it will be considered as local variable & deallocated as soon as come out of loop**

UPDATES:

TO ANSWER "callCenter is declared in appdelegate, how can i use it with self? and other thing when [] added to that block then it shows error on equal to "expected ']' ""

replace self.callCenter with these lines

```
   YourApplicationDelegateClass *appDel =(YourApplicationDelegateClass*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

   appDel.callCenter =  [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
```

Comment: CTCallCenter *callCenter should be declared in Appdelegate and retain it. Otherwise it will be considered as local variable & deallocated as soon as come out of loop.

Comment: callCenter is declared in appdelegate, how can i use it with self? and other thing when [] added to that block then it shows error on equal to "expected ']' "

Comment: replace self.callCenter with these lines   YourApplicationDelegateClass *appDel =(YourApplicationDelegateClass*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    
    appDel.callCenter = block

Comment: when [] added to that block then it shows error on equal to "expected ']' "

Comment: setCallEventHandler:^ not setCallEventHandler=^ . i have updated that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55964/discussion-between-ramani-ashish-and-vijay-apple-dev-blogspot-com).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have done it. As suggested above, I have used it in AppDelegate, but the entire block is also in appDelegate and I don't monitor the state, but check if the call was nil or not.

In AppDelegate.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CTCallCenter *center;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL callWasMade;

@end
```

In AppDelegate.m file

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.center = [[CTCallCenter alloc]init];
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    self.center.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call) {
        if(call!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Call details is not nil, so user must have pressed call button somewhere in the alert view");
            weakSelf.callWasMade = YES;
        }
    };
}
```

Using the `callWasMade` boolean property, you can carry on performing your tasks. This property can be referenced in any ViewController by getting a handle to the AppDelegate. I hope you find this snippet useful.