# call center block executed only once in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:@"9723539389"]];
_PhoneCallWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[_PhoneCallWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];

AppDelegate *appDel =(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

appDel.callCenter =  [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
[appDel.callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall* call)
{
    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
    {
        NSLog(@"Connected");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:2 forKey:@"Connected"];
    }
    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
    {
        NSLog(@"Dialing");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"Dialing"];
    }
    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
    {   
        NSLog(@"Disconnected");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:3 forKey:@"Disconnected"];
    }
    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
    {          
        NSLog(@"Incoming");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Nothing");
    }
}];
```

With above code control goes in block at only dialing. but after that never the block executed at connected or disconnected.

Comment: Maybe you is app is being suspended because it went into the background?

Comment: so how to overcome from that..?

Comment: Well unless your app fall in the apps that are allowed to keep running in the background you don't.

Comment: keep running in background is set but till it only goes into that block only once

Comment: i want to display disconnected in log when i end the call

Comment: possible duplicate of [i want to handle the state of call in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323282/i-want-to-handle-the-state-of-call-in-ios)

Comment: Isn't this question same as the one you posted here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323282/i-want-to-handle-the-state-of-call-in-ios/25262350#25262350