# How to read call duration and phone status on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I understand we cannot extract phone number/ call log from iOS 7. However, how do I give the user a pop-up every time an incoming or outgoing call ends. This pop up will open a form from the App that will already have call duration pre-filled and the user will fill the rest of the call.

I know similar topics exist, but nothing precisely on iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with current versions of iOS (or iOS 8). I wouldn't expect such a facility becoming available any time soon because it doesn't feel like something Apple would allow.

Comment: can there be a background thread that keeps running and fires up the app as soon as a call ends (incoming or outgoing) ?

Comment: You can run your app in the background but there is no guarantee that your app will execute as soon as a call ends.  You cannot force your app into the foreground - only the user can do that.  You could post a local notification prompting the user to enter your app

Comment: how do i read the call status, so, i want to know when the call started and when did it end; giving me call duration and call end time.

Comment: You can use the Core Telephony framework, but it probably won't give you what you want.  I don't think you can achieve what you want without jailbreaking

Comment: I tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323282/i-want-to-handle-the-state-of-call-in-ios    But no luck, ideas ?